# To decide coherent time and fade duration from measured received signal spectrum and relate them to channel modeling

Tags: propagation

This question was asked in Electrical Engineering 2 days ago but hasn't received very informative responses.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387255/decide-coherent-time-and-fade-duration-through-empirical-studies-on-the-channel

I. Scenario: 
 - TX floating in the lossy heterogeneous medium (a mud-like fluid mixed with leaves and small rocks) with undetermined positions within a limited region;
 - RX fixed in the air and closed to the boundary of air-lossy medium;
 - Frequency 500 MHz

II. The study: 
 - The received signal level was recorded every 30 seconds for 30 minutes and sometimes no signal could be detected for a while. The measurement was repeated several times.

III. Results: 
An example of the received signal spectrum is as below.
[image]

Questions:

1. Can I assume 3 minutes to be the coherent time of the channel?
2. Can I assume the no-signal period to be fade duration?
3. How to model the channel when the TX-RX distance was not stable? Can I develop a model for the changes of received signal against time?

Comment: What are the distances involved and what is the transmitter power?

Comment: The distance could be in-between 0.5 to 3 meters. The transmitter power was set to be 18 dBm.

Comment: At that distance and power level, what then is the cause of signal loss? The viscous medium, the antenna patterns, receiver sensitivity or ???

Comment: Basically it's the watery medium while the Tx antenna is too small to be a good radiator. The receiver is a spectrum analyzer which I guess should be fine.

Comment: There is a really good treatment of this area in W.C.Y. Lee's [Mobile Communications Engineering](https://www.amazon.com/Mobile-Communications-Engineering-William-Lee/dp/0070370397).

Comment: Your chart says "An example of the received signal spectrum is as below", but you are showing samples of received signal level over time, not a signal spectrum. Further, there is no scale on the left hand side, dB, % or otherwise.  If it's 10 dB per division, the fades are pretty significant.  If it's 0.01 dB it's negligible.  There's really not nearly enough information provided to answer. your question.